# Windows clients broken after upgrading to bind 9.12

Tags: linux, windows, dns, bind

After upgrading from bind 9.11 to 9.12, Windows (but not Linux) clients on the network started barfing "server not found" error messages for some sites. after a thorough investigation, the problem seems to be that bind 9.12 doesn't send additional data in DNS replies for out of zone cnames and Windows just doesn't do the recursion.

**reply from 9.12:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> imap.asterix.cz @europa.podgorny.cz
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23207
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: d5fa7daebf3a1ffe1805060a5a9d352ffebb15250033a69e (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;imap.asterix.cz.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
imap.asterix.cz.        2463    IN      CNAME   admiral.podgorny.cz.

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 2002:2e24:2741:9900::1#53(2002:2e24:2741:9900::1)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 05 13:16:47 CET 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

reply from 9.11:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> imap.asterix.cz @taurus.asterix.cz
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50822
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 618a6ee9520f91081b7089bf5a9d356ab7eca595939a467c (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;imap.asterix.cz.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
imap.asterix.cz.        3600    IN      CNAME   admiral.podgorny.cz.
admiral.podgorny.cz.    3235    IN      A       46.36.39.65

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
podgorny.cz.            1256    IN      NS      ns3.podgorny.cz.
podgorny.cz.            1256    IN      NS      ns2.podgorny.cz.
podgorny.cz.            1256    IN      NS      ns1.podgorny.cz.

;; Query time: 52 msec
;; SERVER: 2002:2e24:2741:8800::1#53(2002:2e24:2741:8800::1)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 05 13:17:46 CET 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 173
```

so, it seems like there's more questions to ask:

1. How do I make bind 9.12 return full replies? (it seems they removed the additional-from-cache and `additional-from-auth` configuration settings)
2. How do I make Windows resolver do the recursion?
3. What is the "correct" way of solving this? is it Windows' fault? or is bind's default setting bad? is there a rfc for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in 9.12.0 that was fixed now 9.12.1.

https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01598/0/BIND-9.12.1-Release-Notes.html

Comment: thank you for the link. i was starting to think i'm crazy... ;-)